# Preparing a presentation for interview regarding a PhD position

Tags: phd, presentation, interview, physics

I've got invited to a PhD interview in the field of computational physics at a german university. I was asked in the email to prepare a presentation (5min skills, 15min research achievements, 5-10min ideas about the project I would like to work on). I'm struggling with presentations and I'm very unsure what to tell especially in the last part. 
I was sent the research approval that was approved by Deutsche Forschungsgemeinschaft (DFG). So I know the motivation, aims and the basic about the methods that should be used, but I don't know what the Professor wants to hear in this part. Should this part of the presentation be more about my motivation regarding the topic or does he expect me to already give more detailed ideas how to realize the project?

Thank you for any help and suggestions in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Academia.SE! This is a Q&A forum rather than discussion/suggestion forum. Please rewrite your post with focus on the single question you want to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would focus on the research "questions" that you will attempt to answer. What hypotheses you have about the subject in question. Something about how you will begin to attack the questions (methodology), even if not too detailed. If time permits, something about where you think the research would lead you in the future.

If you already have approval for the research, then I suspect that all of this is readily available to you.